# How to pass a null-value color

Tags: c#, null

I just wonder how I can pass a null colour to a method.

Here is an example with a method which gets a color parameter:

```
protected void myMethod(Color color,other parameters...) {}
```

Now I am using the shown condition. Depending on that condition I would like to change the color.

```
if(1) {myMethod(Color.Red,....)}

if(2) {myMethod(Color.Black,...)}

if(3) {myMethod(Color.Ignore,...)} //so here just ignore this color parameter and keep the original.
```

I know I can do many things to overcome this but as I said I just wonder is there any better way of passing an ignore value, so it will use the original color of the element.

Comment: Can't you get the current color somehow or cache it? Maybe you should think about splitting the method into multiple parts

Comment: could you use `null`?

Comment: You can make it a nullable type, `Color?`

Comment: Maybe Color.Transparent ?

Comment: I can get the original color but it is just over use. I think it should be a better way of jsut telling the element the use its own colour instead of getting the elemenets colour and passing it back to it.

Comment: @SamWard `Color` is a value type (an struct) so it cannot be `null`. `Nullable<Color>` (or `Color?`) may be null. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx

Comment: It can be empty: Color.Empty and you can check if a given color variable is empty with the IsEmpty property.

Comment: still over use and extra conditions. it does not sound right I think. then you have another condition.

Comment: Would you consider writing an overload of `myMethod` which doesn't take a `Color` argument? EDIT: Woops, didn't notice there was an answer suggesting exactly this. :)

Answer (score 10):

What about:

```
protected void myMethod(Color? color,other parameters...) {}
```

Where Colour? is nullable, so you can pass null instead and check for the value in your method. If colour == null then keep the original?

Comment: +1. This is exactly what the Nullable<T> class is for, to avoid having magic values like Color.Ignore or Color.Transparent. Or worse, choosing some ugly color no-one will ever want and using that as a the magic value.

Comment: but you need to again use the condition and check it the color is null or not if null then use the original colour. Dont you think this is over use? why we cannot just tell the element to use its own colour?

Answer (score 6):

Create an overload of method which will not require color and call it if you want to use default value (it's better not to provide argument at all, if you are not going to use it in the method than passing `null` value to the method):

```
protected void myMethod(other parameters...)
```

Also I suggest you to put optional parameter to the end of parameters:

```
protected void myMethod(other parameters..,  Color color)
```

Code:

```
switch(value)
{
   case 1: myMethod(..., Color.Red); break;
   case 2: myMethod(..., Color.Black); break;
   case 3: myMethod(...); break;
}
```

You can even ask compiler to make 'overload' (see comments) for you:

```
protected void myMethod(other parameters..,  Color color = {DefaultColor})
```

---

**NOTE**: I like to avoid any confusing code. E.g. call

```
DrawPoint(10, 20, null)
```

looks very confusing to me. What is `null`? Why you are passing null if nobody will be able to use it in the method? Following call looks better

```
DrawPoint(10, 20)
```

It does not mess caller with passing parameters which will not be used. I don't need to think what `null` means. But even in this case we know some information which is still not available for other developers - we are drawing point with default color, and method does not tell anything about it. So, I'd use another method

```
DrawPointWithDefaultColor(10, 20)
```

Completely not confusing.

Comment: Does using the "= default" cause an overload to be created or does the compiler inject the default parameter when the method is called without it?

Comment: @JimRhodes compiler injects default parameter at the place where method called, so actually there will be single method with biggest number of parameters

Comment: Excellent.  Hope he goes with this solution, rather than the "null" type workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply have a an overload that does not take a color object:

```
protected void myMethod(Color color,other parameters...) {}
```

and

```
protected void myMethod(other parameters...) {}
```

OR

Make the colour parameter nullable, that way you can pass null in and just do a null check within the method.

```
protected void myMethod(Color? color,other parameters...) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `myMethod` is written by you , I recommend using a nullable type, as `System.Drawing.Color` is a value type. Therefore, you can write the method like this:

```
protected void myMethod(Color? color,other parameters...) 
{
    if (color == null) // or !Color.HasValue
    {
         // color-is-null logic
    }
    else
    {
         var col = color.Value; 
         // col is an instance of System.Drawing.Color
         // Use `col` instead of color from your current `myMethod` 
         // implementation
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you cannot change that (for instance `myMethod` implements an interface which forces you to use `Color` instead of `Color?`), then you may fallback to passing a meaningless value of the `Color` type. For instance `Color.Transparent` may work, but this is just an assumption. The code for this requires you to change the first if condition of `myMethod`above from

```
    if (color == null) ...
```

to

```
    if (color == Color.Transparent) ...
```

---

**Update**

After the question has been clarified I got better the desired result, Assuming you have refactored the `myMethod` to accept `Color?` instead of `Color`, you can eliminate the boilerplate code:

```
if (1) {myMethod(Color.Red,....)}

if (2) {myMethod(Color.Black,...)}

if (3) {myMethod(Color.Ignore,...)} so here just ignore this color parameter and keep the original.
```

with something like this:

```
Color? color = Colour.Black;
// `color` can be set to `null` or a valid `System.Drawing.Color`
// the followin line will work for both
myMethod(color,...);
```

The magic is that any nullable type can **implicitly** converted from an instance of its underlying type. You would not need if/else statements or casts to pass a `Color` instance to a method that accepts `Color?`, the  runtime will do this for you. The same is valid for passing `null` values.

Comment: yes this is the way I have done it but still I think Microsoft should find a better way of doing this to get rid of unnecessary condition.

Comment: Unfortunately, value types are designed not to work with `null` the way other object do, as they must and are always having a valid non-null value of their type. The `Nullable<>` type is currently the closest solution to your situation - for now. I'd be glad to see if this can improve in any way for the future

Comment: @akdurmus, in any way, I think the condition is necessary. If Color was a reference type, you still would have to check for null or otherwise will end up with a good `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @akdurmus, I see you revisited your question, check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

[Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) is a structure (a value type). So you can use a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) to solve this.

```
protected void MyMethod(Color? color, ...) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would inverse the order of your parameters and make the color parameter nullable and optional. like this:

```
protected void myMethod(other parameters, Color? color = null)
{

    if (color != null)
    {
        // Do something with color
    }
}
```

then you just don't include the parameter when you dont use it:

```
if (3)
{
    myMethod(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a nullable Color parameter, an optional parameter or method overloading. All are code smells though. What you are really doing is providing two types of API functionality:

```
protected void MyMethodWithColorChange(...

protected void MyMethodKeepColorUnchanged(...
```

So create the two methods, with proper names that explain the different functions they perform.